# AttributeError: type object 'BMW' has no attribute 'type'

Tags: python, inheritance, attributeerror

```
class car:
        def __init__(self,model,year):
            self.model = model
            self.year = year


class BMW(car):
    def __init__(self,type,model,year):
        car.__init__(self,model,year)
        self.type = type

class Audi(car):
    def __init__(self,type1,model,year):
        car.__init__(self, model, year)
        self.type1 = type1

d500 = BMW('manual','500d',2020)
print(BMW.type)
print(BMW.model)
print(BMW.year)
```

Comment: you have to call the instantiation of the object rather than the class name. In this case, you name your object `d500`, so you would want to call `d500.type`, `d500.model`, `d500.year`

Comment: Why are you printing `BMW.type` etc.? You should be printing `d500.type` and such. If you do this, your code works fine (tested)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! In fact I laughed at myself looking at that juvenile mistake .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're wondering why the error `AttributeError: type object 'BMW' has no attribute 'type'` is being thrown:

You're instantiating an instance of `BMW` with: `d500 = BMW('manual','500d',2020)`. However, in subsequent lines, you're referring to the class itself rather than the object that you've instantiated.

Since `model`, `year` and `type` are set in the constructor for `car`/`BMW`, `BMW.type` is not defined.

You need to call:

```
print(d500.type)
print(d500.model)
print(d500.year)
```

instead in order to refer to your newly created object.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation bro.it really meant alot

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print the `type` from `BMW`, but you just set that object to the variable `d500`. Use `d500` instead to access the attributes.

```
d500 = BMW('manual','500d',2020)
print(d500.type)
print(d500.model)
print(d500.year)
```

Comment: Yeah bro I did silly mistake but anyways thank you so much for making your time to explain and answer my question..